# iPhone -> problem with UITextfield and NSString -> null value

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an iPhone application and a problem with Strings and UITextfields.

I have this in `viewDidLoad:`:

```
NSLog(@"1: %@", self.myObject.myNSStringProperty);
self.aUITextFieldProperty.text = self.myObject.myNSStringProperty;
NSLog(@"2: %@", self.aUITextFieldProperty.text);
```

The output is:

```
2011-02-13 22:07:32.570 myProject [85241:207] 1: StringTest
2011-02-13 22:07:32.570 myProject [85241:207] 2: (null)
```

Why is the second output `null`?

Best Regards, Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blind guess: because aUITextFieldProperty is nil.

Comment: Doing a `NSLog(@"%@", self.aUITextFieldProperty);` prints on the console `(null)`, so what's wrong?

Comment: You need to initialize `aUITextFieldProperty` - it doesn't exist yet